# How to get the text of an element with id with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Consider:

```html
<tr id="pair_12">
    <td class="left first">
        <span class="ceFlags USD">&nbsp;</span>
        &nbsp; USD
    </td>

    <td class="" id="last_12_12">1</td>
    <td class="pid-2124-last" id="last_12_17">0,8979</td>
    <td class="pid-2126-last" id="last_12_3">0,7695</td>
    <td class="pid-3-last" id="last_12_2">109,94</td>
    <td class="pid-4-last" id="last_12_4">0,9708</td>
    <td class="pid-7-last" id="last_12_15">1,3060</td>
    <td class="pid-2091-last greenBg" id="last_12_1">1,4481</td>
    <td class="pid-18-last greenBg" id="last_12_9">5,8637</td>
</tr>
```

I want to access, for example, the "5,8637" value and it also refreshes for every other second or so. Here is the website maybe it helps you to help me better [link](https://tr.investing.com/currencies/exchange-rates-table).

Answer (score 0):

```
driver = Chrome(webdriver)
driver.get("https://tr.investing.com/currencies/exchange-rates-table")
eur_usd = driver.find_element_by_id("last_17_12").text
```

worked for me!

Comment: Technically your question should be re-phrased to getting the text of an element :) getting a value would be accomplished by `driver.find_element_by_id("last_17_12").get_attribute("value")`. Just some additional info for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
By id = By.id("ANY_ID");
```

Use the *getText(id);* function under Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: It seems like a bogus answer. Perhaps present a complete working example?